# Error: spawn git ENOENT as Nativescript Error

Tags: angular, nativescript

i've updated recently Nativescript to 7.1.2

now when i run my app "tnx run android", this will give me an error below:

```
The current application is not compatible with NativeScript CLI 7.0.

Run 'ns migrate' to migrate your project to NativeScript 7.

Alternatively you may try running it with '--force' to skip this check.
```

Then i try to run "ns migrate", but now gives me this error below and i'm stuck:

```
Error: spawn git ENOENT
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Can someone point me to the right direction on fixing this. i've read countless all over the net but found no solution.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

This error might be gotten due to the lack of a `git` installment or a misconfiguration of `git`. Make sure that:

- You have `git` installed.
- `git` command is directly accessible from your terminal/command prompt, i.e. you should see git version info by typing `git --version` and press Enter.

`ns migrate` command actually examines current git branch and prevents you from continuing migration if you have uncommitted changes. This is why it requires `git`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you followed this steps: https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-7-announcement/?
try to run `ns clean`